# aspx: how can i receive form variables?

Tags: asp.net

I'n new to asp, i would like to know how to receive form variables,

for example:

```
<form id="test" method="post" action="test.aspx">
 <input type="text" name="the_name"/>
 <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

how can i receive properly the the_name value ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your code behind test.aspx.cs file you can do the following:

```
string theName = Request["the_name"]);
```

Comment: Request.Form["the_name"] will be a little more efficient